# Invalid json format exception in AjaxSource Datatables

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I am trying to run this server side [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/JQuery-DataTables-Java.aspx) for jquery [datatable](http://datatables.net), but it keeps on giving the JSON format error.

My jsp code looks like this -

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#companies").dataTable({
              "bServerSide": true,
              "sAjaxSource": "/dummySearchProposals",
              "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
              "iDisplayLength":3,
              "bJQueryUI": true,
          });
      });
      </script>
  <body id="dt_example">
      <div id="container">
          <div id="demo_jui">
      <table id="companies" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                     <th>Company name</th>
                     <th>Address</th>
                     <th>Town</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

and the ajax listener's return object is created using this -

```
        String[] data1 = {"1","a1","a2"};
        String[] data2 = {"2","b1","b2"};
        String[] data3 = {"3","c1","c2"};

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
        data.put(data1);
        data.put(data3);
        data.put(data2);

        outputData.put("sEcho", queryString.get("sEcho"));
        outputData.put("iTotalRecords", "99");
        outputData.put("iTotalDisplayRecords", "3");
        outputData.put("aaData", data);
```

Manually going to the ajax link, returns this -

```
{iTotalDisplayRecords=3, iTotalRecords=99, aaData=[["1","a1","a2"],["3","c1","c2"],["2","b1","b2"]], sEcho=1}
```

Can anyone please suggest, what I might be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like json data that you're getting back from the call. Here is a simple example of a json formatted object.

JSON- name value pairs separated by colons, each pair separated by commas. I threw in array below for good measure.

```
    {"xxx":1, "yyyyy": 2, "z": [1,2,3,4]}
```

Comment: Can you suggest, how do i create the dummy data as mentioned in the example.

Comment: Its giving the same error when I construct it using this - JSONObject outputData = new JSONObject();
  JSONArray data1 = new JSONArray();
  data1.put("Amazon");
  data1.put("as");
  data1.put("df");
  
  JSONArray data2 = new JSONArray();
  data2.put("ms");
  data2.put("as");
  data2.put("df");
  
  JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
  data.put(data1);
  data.put(data2);
  data.put(data3);
  
  outputData.put("sEcho", queryString.get("sEcho"));
  outputData.put("iTotalRecords", "99");
  outputData.put("iTotalDisplayRecords", "3");
  outputData.put("aaData", data);